# Process terminated unexpected when increment elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks

What's wrong with this piece of code?

the one resulted in error:

```
 for(int i=0; primeArr[i]!=0; ++i)
{
    int tempSum=0;
    for(int j=i; primeArr[j]!=0 && tempSum<=10000; ++j)
    {
        tempSum=tempSum+primeArr[j];   //error happend here, if this code is discared it will no longer terminated
        sumCount[tempSum]++;           //same as above, if discarded the code will be okay

    }
}
```

the one without error:

```
     for(int i=0; primeArr[i]!=0; ++i)
{
        int flag=i, cnt=primeArr[flag];
        while(cnt<=10000)
        {
            sumCount[cnt]++;
            ++flag;
            cnt+=primeArr[flag];
        }
}
```

The error is :Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) in Code::Blocks

Comment: Is there `0` in array ? And what is size of `primeArr` ?

Comment: can't really tell what the error is with just this info. have you tried running it with lldb?

Comment: Your code is not complete enough to be verifiable.

Comment: `primeArr` being undeclared is a major problem. `sumCount` has the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding to `tempsum` (the index), incrementing the count, then checking the bounds.  The loop that works increments the changes the index (`cnt`).

The addition to `tempsum` puts it past the bounds of `sumCount`.  When you try to increment the count in that state the process terminates with the invalid memory access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it turns out the access to the array beyond the   range.

Answer (score 1):

`j` probably went out of range of the `primeArr` array. i.e. `j` is equal to or greater than number of elements in `primeArr` array.

To fix that, first store the number of elements in `primeArr` array to a variable `arrLength`. Then, add another check condition to your loops:

```
for(int i=0; i < arrLength && primeArr[i]!=0; ++i)
{
    int tempSum=0;
    for(int j=i; j < arrLength && primeArr[j]!=0 && tempSum<=10000; ++j)
    {
        tempSum=tempSum+primeArr[j];   //error happend here, if this code is discared it will no longer terminated
        sumCount[tempSum]++;           //same as above, if discarded the code will be okay
    }
}
```

Same for the second block of code:

```
for(int i=0; i < arrLength && primeArr[i]!=0; ++i)
{
        int flag=i, cnt=primeArr[flag];
        while(cnt<=10000)
        {
            sumCount[cnt]++;
            ++flag;
            cnt+=primeArr[flag];
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you've probably guessed the poblem correctly but those new conditions don't terminate the loop earlier than the original.

Comment: The new check should be applied first. This will prevent the out of bound access even before it happens and will not check the second condition of the && when it is going out of bound.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved by the answer below.But still appreciate your patient answer.